# How to source .vimrc inside a function in .vimrc?

Tags: vimrc, functions

This is part of my vimrc--

```
function! Abbreviations()
    let a:code=input("Which Abbreviation: ")

    "gen
    if(a:code=="gen")
    source ~/.vim/Abbreviations/GeneralAbbreviations.vim
    endif

    "math
    if(a:code=="math")
    source ~/.vim/Abbreviations/MathAbbreviations.vim
    endif
endfunction


function! SourceAbbreviations()
    :execute ":normal! :source $MYVIMRC\<cr>:call Abbreviations()\<cr>gen\<cr>:call Abbreviations()\<cr>math\<cr>"
endfunction

nnoremap <buffer> <localleader>e :call SourceAbbreviations()<cr>
```

As you can see the function `SourceAbbreviations()` has to call other functions. When I do `:call SourceAbbreviations()` it shows an error. However, if I remove `:source $MYVIMRC\<cr>` from the function `SourceAbbreviations()`, it works. So, what's actually wrong in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would advise you to do the following:

First change the function `Abbreviations()` to accept an argument and maybe not use the interactive mode:

```
function! Abbreviations(code)
  if a:code != 'gen' && a:code != 'math'
    let l:code = input("Which Abbreviation: ")
  else
    let l:code = a:code
  endif
  if l:code == "gen"
    source ~/.vim/Abbreviations/GeneralAbbreviations.vim
  endif
  if l:code == "math"
    source ~/.vim/Abbreviations/MathAbbreviations.vim
  endif
endfunction
```

Now you can `:call Abbreviations("gen")` or `:call Abbreviations("math")` or `:call Abbreviations("")` to get the old behaviour.

Second simplify the function `SourceAbbreviations()` like so

```
function! SourceAbbreviations()
  execute "source" $MYVIMRC
  call Abbreviations("gen")
  call Abbreviations("math")
endfunction
```

But if you are really keen on using your complex `:execute` command you should take `$MYVIMRC` out of the string as this is vimscript and not shell. So write

```
:execute ":normal! :source " . $MYVIMRC . "\<cr>:call Abbreviations()\<cr>gen\<cr>:call Abbreviations()\<cr>math\<cr>"
```

In order to understand this compare these two

```
echo $MYVIMRC
echo "$MYVIMRC"
```

Comment: Hey, Thanks for helping me out. I made all the changes you suggested, still it showed an error; and it referred to the line `endfunction` in the function `SourceAbbreviations()`. I think the problem is that if I put `source $MYVIMRC` in this function, it creates a loop. I don't know for sure though.

Comment: Please post the error message/number, that is always important. Do you call the function from your vimrc file? Why do you need to source the vimrc file from within the function? Maybe you can turn the function into an autoload function (see `:h autoload`).

Comment: I did try adding autocmds for this, and it wasn't working; but today when I did it it worked! I don't know why it didn't work earlier, I did not change anything else that could affect it. Anyway thanks.